# Confusion on pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I was practising with pointers and came across this thing.
The following code gives the answer:

```
 1
 0
 3
```

when I change *a with *c the answer is same but on changing with *b=0, the answer is

```
1
2
0
```

Can you please what is going on behind the scenes in each of these processes?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void func(int *a, int *b,int *c)
{
    a=b;
    b=c;
    c=a;
    *a=0;

}


int main()
{
    int a=1,b=2,c=3;
    func(&a,&b,&c);
    cout<<a<<endl<<b<<endl<<c;

}
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier to talk about if you used different names for the variables in main than you did for the parameters of the function.

Comment: yeah. I know. My bad! But still the question would be equally tricky for me. I got it at last. Thanks to one of the answerers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

For easier reading, I'll rename the variables in `func` to `pa`, `pb` and `pc`. So what you're mixing up in `func` makes:

- `pa` point to what `pb` is pointing to (`b`)
- `pb` point to what `pc` is pointing to (`c`)
- `pc` point to what `pa` is pointing to (which is now `b`)

Therefore

```
*pa = 0
```

follows `pa`'s pointer (to `b`) and sets that to 0, giving you:

```
a = 1
b = 0
c = 3
```

However

```
*pb = 0
```

instead follows `pb`'s pointer (to `c`) and sets that to 0, giving you:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You are first swapping pointers; the only relevant line is:

```
a=b;
```

So the variable `a` in `func` now points to the address of `b` in your main.

Then

```
*a=0;
```

sets the value of the variable `a` in `func` is pointing to (which is `b` in your main now) to `0`.

So, `a`, `b`, `c` are pointers to things, while `a`, `b`, `c` are "things". It become easier when you rename the variables in `func` to something else, for example: `pa`, `pb` and `pc` as "pointer-to-a". Then you can see you are swapping pointers and that `*pa=0` is "setting the value `pa` is pointing to to `0`.

Keeping this in mind, it should become clear that modifying your code will swap pointers differently, and thus leads to different results.

Answer (score 0):

> when I change *a with *c the answer is same

Why would you expect any different? You wrote `c=a;` just above it.

> changing with *b=0, the answer is 1 2 0

Indeed, you wrote `b=c;` before it, so writing `0` in `*b` will zero out the third parameter's contents.

Comment: Do note that this is beyond pointless and intentionally confusing. If you're really trying stuff out to learn C, you'd be better off learning how to code cleanly than how to write code I'd fire you on the spot for writing.

Comment: What I am thinking may sound little awkward but please correct me if I am wrong. A now points to B so whatever change occurs in A will be made in B instead of A. In second step, whatever change occurs in B has to be made in C. So if we change *a to 0, that means b memory should get 0 but it being told that this change is to be made in C, C gets 0 now. However C again points to a. So ultimately a gets 0! So it must be 0 2 3 and not 1 0 3. Please correct me with the logic.

Comment: @AtraenteHomem, `c` does not point to the original `a`, you overwrote it to point to the original `b` previously. Again I'll say you're pointlessly confusing yourself with these names. Pick better ones.